# How to unassign a 1.14 Minecraft Villager's career in survival, no villager farm

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is there some way I can make something like a Farmer turn into a Weaponsmith or a Toolsmith? without creative or cheats?

Comment: Seems like you just need to put them near different workstations (which seems weird, but ok, villagers were always a bit weird). If that doesn't work, you can abuse [a bug](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-148564): Turn them into zombie villagers and cure them, then they lose their profession.

Answer (score 2):

The Village & Pillage Update (v1.14) now lets you control a Villager's [Profession](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Villager#Professions), with the use of [job site blocks](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Villager#Job_site_blocks) or "Workstations". These blocks can be "claimed" by Villagers, at a 1:1 ratio (one villager to one workstation).

If a Villager's workstation is destroyed, or they can no longer path find to that block (this can include moving beyond a certain radius of the block), they will lose their Profession, and can then be re-assigned a new one. Villagers must be at least one block away from a workstation, and be able to pathfind to the block to be assigned a new profession.

The exceptions to this are that Villagers cannot be [Nitwits](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Villager#Nitwit), or babies. Villagers that you have traded with prior to v1.14 [can still be assigned a new Profession](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/351724/are-pre-existing-villagers-affected-by-workstations) by workstations. Additionally, there is a [bug in v1.14 pre-release 4](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-148564) that can be abused:

> Cured zombie villagers lose profession